# How to count rows with data, starting from a certain row to the last one?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to count rows with data, starting from a certain row to the last one.

Let's pretend in column "A" I have these three rows:
150
185
350

With this code:

```vb
LastRow = sht.Range(SpecificColumn & StartingRow).End(xlUp).Row
```

With these values:
SpecificColumn = "A"
StartingRow = 1  or 2 or 3

I always get LastRow = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direction will be down, not up. Try-

```
LastRow = sht.Range(SpecificColumn & StartingRow).End(xlDown).Row
```

Or

```
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```